# Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not locate field name on class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Hello I have 2 entities **Country** with embeddedId property

```
@IdClass(Country.class)
@Entity
@Table(name="country")
public class Country implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="code", length=3, nullable=false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name="name", length=256, nullable=false)
    private String name;
    @EmbeddedId
    private CountryLanguage language;

    public CountryLanguage getCountryLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setCountryLanguage(CountryLanguage language) {
        this.language = language;
    }
```

CountryLanguage embedded class with getters and setters

```
@Embeddable
public class CountryLanguage {

    @Column(name="country_code", length=3, nullable=false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name="language", length=256, nullable=false)
    private String language;

    @Column(name="is_official", length=256, nullable=false)
    private boolean official;
```

I have an Exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null springbootapp    
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212] springbootapp    
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212] springbootapp    
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_212] springbootapp    
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_212] springbootapp    
at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final] springbootapp    
... 46 common frames omitted springbootapp    
 Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not locate field name [official] on class [hello.world.entity.Country]
```

Comment: The stack trace tells you what's wrong. You try to access a field 'official' in 'Country',  but the field is in 'Countrylanguage'.

Comment: The @IdClass(Country.class) is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Only one of `@IdClass` and `@EmbeddedId` approaches is needed. Further, the `@IdClass` is wrong as the class of the embedded id is `CountryLanguage`. Also the `code` field on `Country` annotated with `@Id` and `@Column` conflicts with `code` field on `CountryLanguage` annotated with `@Column`.

For the `@EmbeddedId` approach, removing the `@IdClass` annotation together with the `@Id` on `code` should fix the issue.

Comment: When I removed **@IdClass** then I have Exception `This class [class hello.world.entity.Country] does not define an IdClass`

Comment: Why? I have main class Country and another CountryLanguage which doesnt have a primary key.

Comment: ```springbootapp    | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given domain class does not contain an id attribute!```

Comment: @EmbeddedId is used to declare composite primary key on a class for given table. IdClass is used for the same purpose. Only one of those are needed.

Comment: As for `IllegalArgumentException` - do you still have that `@EmbeddedId` over `language`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207164/discussion-between-michal-and-doctordo).